# compare multidimensional scaling matrix

Tags: r, plot, multi-dimensional-scaling

I have two MDS plot for the same 356 items, what is the best thing that I can do to compare these two plots?

I tried to use Procrustes in R but I did not like the result that I get is there another functions I can use in R to compare them?

```
dat1 <- read.csv("file1.r",sep=" ", header=FALSE)
distdat1 <- dist(dat1)
isores1 <- isoMDS(distdat1)

dat2 <- read.csv("file2.r",sep=" ", header=FALSE)
distdat2 <- dist(dat2)
isores2 <- isoMDS(distdat2)

pro <- procrustes(isores2,isores1)
plot(pro,kind=2)
text(pro,cex=0.2)
```

Comment: Do you have sample code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I just add a sample of the code that I use